# R equivalent of Parametric Survial Model in Python by fitting a Weibull Regression

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels

The survival library in R provides Regression methods for fitting a Parametric Survival model. I'm trying to reproduce their example using Python. I found that `statsmodel` provides methods for [Survival Analysis](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/duration.html) using Cox models but I couldn't find a method for fitting Weibull distribution.

Below is the R example which I would like to reproduce from [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/survreg.html)

```
library(survival)

survreg(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + age + strata(sex), 
    data = lung, dist = "weibull")

Output:
Coefficients:
(Intercept)     ph.ecog         age 
 6.73234505 -0.32443043 -0.00580889 

Scale:
    sex=1     sex=2 
0.7834211 0.6547830 

Loglik(model)= -1137.3   Loglik(intercept only)= -1146.2
    Chisq= 17.8 on 2 degrees of freedom, p= 0.000137 
n=227 (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
```

This dataset can be loaded in Python using Statsmodels

```
import statsmodels.api as sm    
data = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("lung", package='survival').data
```

I would like to know if its possible to reproduce the above results using `statsmodels` or any of the other Python packages . Calling R functions from Python using`rpy2` would be my last option.

Comment: `lifelines` package has some of it https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifelines.fitters.html , but I don't know how close that is to R's functionality. statsmodels does not have parametric survival models yet (except in some draft code.) https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4217

Comment: Thanks for the links. I see that its an issue from 2018. I'll try to reproduce some of the results from 'lifelines' package.